# Markdown - PHP parser

Tags: javascript, php, composer-php, markdown, php-parser

Do you know about some markdown `PHP` parser, with `code highlight`, etc, like the `GitHub` markdown parser or https://stackedit.io/editor?

If it is available via `Composer` then better.

I've tried:

https://packagist.org/packages/michelf/php-markdown

https://packagist.org/packages/league/commonmark

https://packagist.org/packages/erusev/parsedown

but the result of all these are almost plain text.

The best result belongs to `michelf/php-markdown` as you can see on the following image:

[image]

```
$ composer require michelf/php-markdown

---

use Michelf\MarkdownExtra;

$parser = new MarkdownExtra();
$html = $parser->transform($markdown);

echo $html;
```

**[EDIT 1]**

Now I'm almost at my goal.

I used:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css

And now I get a result very similar to `GitHub` but the code is not getting `highlighted` (with `colors`) according the corresponded `language` (on this case: `html`) as you can see on the following image:

[image]

Then my **QUESTION** now is:

> what extra step do I need to do in order to get code syntax highlight like GitHub does?. Please, check the following GitHub's output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are missing CSS styles for the rendered HTML.

The generated HTML looks actually ok.

Try to include the styles in the document where you echo the `$html`.

For example use Github styles like this:
 https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot. I did an **edit** on my post above because now as last step I need to highlight the code with colors according to the language syntax.

Comment: Use https://highlightjs.org for syntax highlighting.

Comment: thanks, that helped!